# RequireJS Optimizer throws ReferenceError: text is not defined

Tags: requirejs, r.js, requirejs-text

I have been using r.js to attempt to minify a fairly large project and I'm having trouble with the text plugin. I am using node.js and a build file that goes as follows:

**Build File**

```
({

    name: '../main',

    baseUrl: '../../js/app',

    appDir: "./app",

    dir: 'build',

    paths: {

        jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        underscore: '../lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: '../lib/backbone/backbone-min',
        text: '../lib/require/text',
        picker: '../lib/pickadate/picker',
        pickerDate: '../lib/pickadate/picker.date',
        pickerLegacy: '../lib/pickadate/legacy'
    },

    mainConfigFile : '../js/main.js'

})
```

**Main Config File**

```
requirejs.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/app',

    paths: {

        jquery: '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        underscore: '../lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: '../lib/backbone/backbone-min',
        text: '../lib/require/text',
        picker: '../lib/pickadate/picker',
        pickerDate: '../lib/pickadate/picker.date',
        pickerLegacy: '../lib/pickadate/legacy'
    },

    shim: {
        picker: ['jquery', 'pickerLegacy'],
        pickerDate: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'picker'],
            exports: 'DatePicker'
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: '_'
        },
        text : {
            exports : 'text'
        }
    }

});
```

The references above are all verified correct. Whenever I try to compile this, I get the following output in the console:

```
node r.js -o app.build.js

Tracing dependencies for: ../main
ReferenceError: text is not defined
In module tree:
    ../main
      app
        router
          views/pages/home
            views/panel/allStoresPanel
              text

Error: ReferenceError: text is not defined
In module tree:
    ../main
      app
        router
          views/pages/home
            views/panel/allStoresPanel
              text

    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\code\Web\DixonsDashboard\deploy\_compiler\r.js:23699:64), <anonymous>:1:1)
```

I have no idea why it finds text to be undefined. The path to it is definitely correct - the site works like a charm in it's current expanded format. I have tried all of the options available to r.js and none of them seem to make any difference.

If I delete the file, I get a "No such file or directory" error, so it looks like it's finding the file OK.

Can anybody point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: A rule I follow is that `baseUrl` is the folder that contains the scripts, *relative to the HTML page that loads them, **not** relative to build.js*. According to this my `baseUrl` for the build file and the config file is the same. Could you give it a try?

Comment: I gave it a try but I got a slew of other errors instead. I moved the compiler scripts into the directory with the main module with the same result, unfortunately =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only configure `shim` for plugins that are *not* AMD compatible. The "text" plugin is already AMD compatible so running it through the `shim` mechanism actually breaks it.

---

I've just tested with a simplified version of your code: including text in the `shim` section does show "ReferenceError: text is not defined", removing it makes the build work fine.

Comment: I will totally try this out when I can next access my repo and let you know how it goes.